# How do I retrieve a row from a SQLite database through Java's jdbc using a string variable?

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

This should return the row where name is equal to the String variable name, however all I get is this error

> [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "Wars": syntax error)

In this instance I tried to use "Star Wars" as the name variable since I'm using a movies database. What am I doing wrong?

```
 public void selectName(ObservableList<Movies> movieList, String name){
    String sql = "SELECT id, name, year FROM movies WHERE name = " + name + " ";

    try(Connection conn = this.Connect();
        Statement stm = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery(sql)){
        while(rs.next()){
            movieList.addAll(new Movies(rs.getInt("id"),rs.getString("name"),rs.getInt("year")));
        }
    }catch(SQLException ex){
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
```

Comment: Normally SQL statements that compare Strings need the 'STRING' inside of it, so your sql variable should look like:

SELECT id, name, year FROM movies WHERE name = "Star wars";

for that, change it to:

"SELECT id, name, year FROM movies WHERE name = \"" + name + "\"";

Comment: USE PARAMETERS..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you received the error is that you are executing `[..] where name = Star Wars` which is invalid. If you were using a literal query string (where the value is fixed and not user input), the correct query would be `[..] where name = 'Star Wars'`.

The simple solution would seem to be to enclose the value in single quotes, however you should **never** concatenate values into query strings (especially not if they are user input) as this leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection.

Instead you should use a parametrized query (aka prepared statement) and set the parameter value. This way the driver will properly handle the parameter in a way that avoids potential SQL injection risks.

Specifically, you should do something like:

```
try (PreparedStatemet select = connection.prepareStatement(
        "SELECT id, name, year FROM movies WHERE name = ?")) {
    select.setString(1, name);
    try (ResultSet rs = select.executeQuery() {
        // process result set
    }
}
```